# Open the Word file in the active Workbook directory

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set the path to my Workbook file, which I want to be opened from the same directory, where my current workbook is based.
I saw some solution here:

[Open File Without Calling Filepath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888011/open-file-without-calling-filepath)

and my code currently looks like this:

```
 Sub RamsOpen3()
 Dim appWD As Word.Application
 Set appWD = New Word.Application
 Dim docWD As Word.Document
 Set docWD = appWD.Documents.Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "RAMS.docx.docm")         
  appWD.Visible = True
 '
 ' Data is selected and copied into "Design"
 '
 'Copy all data from Design
 Sheets("Frontsheet").Select
 Range("D18").Copy
' Tell Word to create a new document

 appWD.Selection.Paste
' Save the new document with a sequential file name
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
appWD.ActiveDocument.SaveAs filename:=ThisWorkbook.path & "/" & "TEST" & Range("C8").Text
' Close this new word document
appWD.ActiveDocument.Close
' Close the Word application
appWD.Quit
End Sub
```

The line of code is in red, and the debugger says: **Expected end of statement**.

[image]

It excludes also the option with Dim filename as string, proposed in the linked query above.

Does anyone know how to coup with it?

Comment: You are missing the left parenthesis `(` after `Open`

Comment: Ah yes, thank you!