# VBA Flexible file address to open the file

Tags: vba, macos, solidworks

I have a macro on a flash drive that I want to run on different computers. After running, this macro opens a file located in the macro's own folder in the flash drive.

```
Set Part = swApp.OpenDoc6("F:\RSO_Regal.SLDASM", 2, 0, "", longstatus, longwarnings)
Set Part = swApp.OpenDoc6("RSO_Regal.SLDASM", 2, 0, "", longstatus, longwarnings)
```

My problem is that every time I connect a flash drive to a new computer or copey the folder in new directory, I have to edit the file address in the macro.
Is there a solution to this problem?

There is a solution to this problem for Microsoft Excel in this post.
[Open File Without Calling Filepath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888011/open-file-without-calling-filepath)
However, my macro is for SolidWorks software and it opens a file with *.SLDASM format.

Comment: Will placing the macro file in the same folder of the `SLDASM` file and using `ThisWorkbook.Path` in place of drive or path letter would work like `Set Part = swApp.OpenDoc6(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\RSO_Regal.SLDASM", 2, 0, "", longstatus, longwarnings)`?

Comment: I changed the code and got the following error message.
`Set Part = swApp.OpenDoc6(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\RSO_Regal.SLDASM", 2, 0, "", longstatus, longwarnings)`

Error:
**Run-time error '424'**
**Object required**

Note: VBA macro is for Solidworks CAD software. I don't want open an Excel Workbook.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the macro path using **GetCurrentMacroPathName** and use that to open the file. Check the changed line below.

```
Set Part = swApp.OpenDoc6(Left(swApp.GetCurrentMacroPathName, InStrRev(swApp.GetCurrentMacroPathName, "\")) & "RSO_Regal.SLDASM", 2, 0, "", longstatus, longwarnings)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This code Work. There is only one problem. The output of this code is **F:\RSO_Regal.swpRSO_Regal.SLDASM**. But I need only the file path without the macro name and extension: **F:\RSO_Regal.SLDASM**.  Note: **RSO_Regal.swp** is the name and extension of macro data

Comment: It seems that SO didn't show the \ between the quotes. So add a \ between the quotes in this line **swApp.GetCurrentMacroPathName, ""**

I've also updated the above answer.